# How to filter column based on another column date range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I currently have a dataframe where 1st column is dates (1990 - 2020) and the subsequent columns are 'stocks' that are trading and are NaN if they are not yet being traded.  Is there any way to filter the columns based on date range? For example, if 2 years is selected, all stocks that are not null in all columns from 2019-2020 (2 years) will be filtered in.

```
import pandas as pd
    
df = pd.read_csv("prices.csv")
df.head()
display(df)

date    s_0000  s_0001  s_0002  s_0003  s_0004  s_0005  s_0006  s_0007  s_0008  ... s_2579  s_2580  s_2581  s_2582  s_2583  s_2584  s_2585  s_2586  s_2587  s_2588
0   1990-01-02  NaN 13.389421   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 0.266812    NaN ... NaN 1.950358    NaN 7.253997    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   1990-01-03  NaN 13.588601   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 0.268603    NaN ... NaN 1.985185    NaN 7.253997    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   1990-01-04  NaN 13.610730   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 0.269499    NaN ... NaN 1.985185    NaN 7.188052    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   1990-01-05  NaN 13.477942   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 0.270394    NaN ... NaN 1.985185    NaN 7.188052    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
4   1990-01-08  NaN 13.477942   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 0.272185    NaN ... NaN 1.985185    NaN 7.385889    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
7806    2020-12-23  116.631310  22.171579   15.890000   16.577030   9.00    65.023491   157.495850  130.347580  27.481012   ... 19.870001   42.675430   2.90    8.850000    9.93    NaN 0.226   207.470001  158.974014  36.650002
7807    2020-12-24  116.641243  21.912146   15.660000   16.606722   8.77    65.292725   158.870193  131.352829  27.813406   ... 20.180000   42.508686   2.88    8.810000    9.91    NaN 0.229   205.270004  159.839264  36.009998
7808    2020-12-28  117.158287  22.191536   16.059999   16.200956   8.93    66.429459   157.011383  136.050766  28.272888   ... 19.959999   42.528305   2.69    8.760000    9.73    NaN 0.251   199.369995  161.500122  36.709999
7809    2020-12-29  116.561714  21.991972   15.860000   16.745275   8.80    66.529175   154.925140  134.239273  27.705866   ... 19.530001   41.949623   2.59    8.430000    9.61    NaN 0.243   197.839996  162.226105  36.610001
7810    2020-12-30  116.720795  22.899990   16.150000   17.932884   8.60    66.299828   155.884232  133.094650  27.725418   ... 19.870001   42.390987   2.65    8.540000    9.72    NaN 0.230   201.309998  163.369812  36.619999
```

so I want to do something like:

```
year = input(Enter number of years:)
year = 3
```

If year is 3, the daterange selected would be 3 years to 2020 (2018-2020)

Comment: can you provide an example of how you would call this filter? which input would you feed?

Comment: Assuming you are using data objects in the date column you can use comparisons, e.g., `< x`. Use date and timedelta objects to get the ranges you want.

Comment: hey but what if i would like to use user input to determine the number of year? so I want to do something like: year = input(Enter number of years:) year = 3 If year is 3, the date range selected would be 3 years to 2020 (2018-2020)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following code:

```py
df[(df['date'] >= '2019-01-01') & (df['date'] <= '2020-12-30')]
```

Once you filter, you could remove all rows, which include NaN:

```py
df.dropna()
```

Comment: hey but what if i would like to use user input to determine the number of year?     so I want to do something like:

year = input(Enter number of years:)
year = 3
If year is 3, the date range selected would be 3 years to 2020 (2018-2020)

Comment: Following on from this.  If you convert your `date` column to datetime: `df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])`, then set your input to be `year = int(input("Enter number of years: "))`, you can then filter by: `df[(df["date"] >= str(df.date.max().year - year + 1))]`.  You need to add the 1 so that it will capture start of 2018 to end of 2020, rather than start of 2017 to end of 2020.  From what you have said, it seems as though you always want to the latest date, so there is no need for an upper bound (e.g. `<= '2020'`).

Comment: And if the end will always be 2020, you can change `df.date.max().year` to `2020`.